# アメッシュ etymology

Tags: etymology, suffixes

There is a weather app called アメッシュ. I get that the first part of the word is 雨「あめ」, but what's the meaning of the suffix 〜ッシュ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

アメッシュ (a registered trademark Tokyo Metropolitan Government), refers to [the system](http://tokyo-ame.jwa.or.jp/en/index.html) which tells us how much rainfall is observed at each location in the metropolitan area.

The data is given in the form of grid, or *mesh*, consisting of 150m*150m squares (cf. [Tokyo Amesh/About Tokyo Amesh](http://tokyo-ame.jwa.or.jp/en/amesh/kansoku.html)) . Apparently this is where -ッシュ comes from.

Comment: Aha, so it's a [portmanteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau)!